# To confirm a possible mistake/typo in the book "PROBABILITY AND STOCHASTICS (GTM 261)". Limit arising from a filtration.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

[image]
In Proposition 4.16, it is written that $\mathcal{F}_{T}=\lim_{n}\mathcal{F}_{T\wedge n}$.

Recall that given a sequence of sets $(A_{n})$, if $A_{1}\subseteq A_{2}\subseteq\ldots$,
then we denote $\lim_{n}A_{n}:=\cup_{n}A_{n}$.
If $A_{1}\supseteq A_{2}\supseteq\ldots$, we also denote $\lim_{n}A_{n}:=\cap_{n}A_{n}$.

Therefore, in our case, the symbol $\lim_{n}\mathcal{F}_{T\wedge n}$
actually means $\lim_{n}\mathcal{F}_{T\wedge n}:=\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{F}_{T\wedge n}$.

However, in general, $\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{F}_{T\wedge n}$
is not a $\sigma$-algebra even the sequence of $\sigma$-algebras
is increasing.

For example, if this were true, by taking $T=\infty$, then $\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{F}_{n}$
is a $\sigma$-algebra, which is false in general.

Comment: I guess it means to take the smallest sigma algebra containing the union.

Comment: If so, it should be denoted by $\bigvee_n \mathcal{F}_{T\wedge n}$. Actually, the author did this.